# ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the `predict` method in my logistical regression class with list `X_test`. However, the code crashes with this error:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis
> must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has
> size 800 and the array at index 1 has size 200

If anyone knows how to get round this issue that would be greatly appreciated!

```
X = numerical_df.drop(['Class'], axis = 1)
y = numerical_df['Class']

k:int = 5
elapsed: float = 0;
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=None)
accuracy_score = []

for train_index, test_index in k_fold.split(X):
    X_train , X_test = X.iloc[train_index,:],X.iloc[test_index,:]
    y_train , y_test = y[train_index] , y[test_index]

    model = LogisticRegression(X_train, y_train)

    start = time.time()
    model.fit(0.1, 5000)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test, 1)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
    accuracy_score.append(acc)

    elapsed += time.time() - start
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the code -
`LogisticRegression()` should not be initialized with training data

`model.fit` will have train and test data as its params

`accuracy_score` is a function, and should not be mixed with a variable

try this -

```
k:int = 5
elapsed: float = 0;
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=k, random_state=None)
accuracy_scores = []

for train_index, test_index in k_fold.split(X):
    X_train , X_test = X.iloc[train_index,:],X.iloc[test_index,:]
    y_train , y_test = y[train_index] , y[test_index]

    model = LogisticRegression()

    start = time.time()
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
    accuracy_scores.append(acc)

    elapsed += time.time() - start
```